# Add [fa-18] as a synonym of [f-18]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I ran across a question about a F/A-18 Hornet that lacked the tag for the aircraft.

The official tag is [f-18](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/f-18), but the offical name is [F/A 18 Hornet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F/A-18_Hornet). If you try to tag it as "fa" anything, no aircraft tags are suggested. It took me a minute (and my knowledge of how SE tagging works) to figure out what the proper tag is. A quick synonym of [fa-18] could be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made the tag [fa-18](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fa-18) and made [f-18](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/f-18) a [synonym](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tags/fa-18/synonyms).

<sub>I did this a number of days ago, I just forgot to come back and post this answer. Apologies for the tardiness!</sub>